# Как убрать дубли во вставке в таблицу при выполнении запроса на выборку?

Tags: sql

Выполняю следующий запрос:

[image: Таблица]

Необходимо вставить в таблицу данные по условию запроса. Сам запрос корректно работает. Но если нажать кнопку "Выполнить" несколько раз, то в таблице "Запросы" будет дубляж одной и той же строчки. От этого дублирования мне и нужно избавиться.

Также привел саму таблицу, где видно повтор строк.

[image: Таблица]

Попробовал использовать `NOT EXISTS` (также приложу скриншот запроса), но оно вообще ничего не добавляет в таблицу. Читал про `NOT IN`, но так и не понял, как вообще это исправить.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Создать уникальный индекс по идентифицирующей группе полей.

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: `merge` заюзать.

Comment: в exists не надо ничего в селект выбирать. либо * либо 1. он вообще не выполняется сам по себе. сервер фиксирует что-то есть в выборке, и не извлекает сами данные, они в этом случае не нужны.